# JMeter getting non HTTP Response Message "Remote host closed connection during handshake"

Tags: ssl, jmeter, httpresponse, haproxy

This is my error message I got for many threads/requests in JMeter 2.11, if I'm sending 100 Threads/requests in 10s to a webserver which is configured with HAProxy 1.6.4. This server is redirecting the requests with simple round robin to 2 web-servers.

> Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
>
> Response message: Non HTTP response message: Remote host closed connection during handshake

The load balancing server is staying "cool" (enough CPU, RAM).

If I'm sending the request direct to one of the webservers, it is working without errors. So I guess the error is causing by HAProxy...

I did't find a limit for HAProxy max open (SSL) connections or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: I set the limit on my own in the config file. `maxconn` is the parameter I had to set higher.

Comment: Which config file?

Comment: The config file of HAProxy which you are using server-side. Something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282514/haproxy-tuning-for-performance